# Toggling visibility using ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

Im not sure why the following is not working.  I am attempting  hiding and showing a textbox every .2 seconds for 1.2 seconds when the bound model property changes. can anyone see an issue with this style or how i am attempting to do this?

```
<Style x:Key="FlashStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated" >
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.8" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.QuotePrice, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource FlashStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Binding.TargetUpdated` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.targetupdated.aspx) does not occur:

> Occurs when a value is transferred from the binding source to the binding target, but only for bindings with the [`NotifyOnTargetUpdated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.notifyontargetupdated.aspx) value set to **`true`**.

Only thing i can think of besides [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (which should be fine if this is your actual code).